# How to set wordpress as primary domain and laravel as subdomain?

Tags: php

I am use Digital Ocean as hosting server. I have one primary domain named like example.com

I set wordpress project on this primary domain `[example.com]`. Now i have one folder named 'mysubproject' and i have to set my laravel project with subdomain like `company.example.com`

Subdomain is dynamic like `company.example.com,company2.example.com,company1.example.com`.

Every subdomain point to same directory `mysubproject` [access same project]

My directory stracture is like this:

```
> mysubproject [sub folder where i have to place my laravel project]
> wp-admin
> wp-content
> wp-include
> index.php
```

I can run my laravel project with this url :

`company.example.com/mysubproject`

But i have to remove `mysubproject` folder and access laravel project.

How can i do this? Is there any HTACCESS rules for that?

I tried this:

`RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^company\.example\.com
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.example\.com/mysubproject/$1 [L]`

this also :

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/mysubproject/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]`

But NOT WORKS